# Cannot call to model of polymorphic relation

Tags: laravel

I'm trying to reach a (ex.) visitable_id: 38 visitable_type: App\Thread in a polymorphic relationship. I can do it with the User with the code below, but can't seem to do it with the thread:

Blade:

```
    @foreach ($visits as $visit)
        @if($visit->visitable_type == 'App\User')
        Viewing member profile <a href="/profiles/{{ $visit->user->name }}">{{ $visit->user->name }}</a>
        @endif
        @if($visit->visitable_type == 'App\Thread')
        Viewing thread <a href="/forums/{{ $visit->channel->slug }}/{{ $visit->slug }}/">
        {{ $visit->title }}</a>
        @endif
    @endforeach
```

Controller:

```
$visits = Visit::where('user_id', $user->id)->get();
```

Models:
User:

```
public function visits()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Visit::class, 'visitable');
}

public function visit()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Visit::class, 'visitable');
}
```

Models: Visit:

```
public function user()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
}

public function thread()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Thread::class);
}

public function visitable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

Models: Thread:

```
public function visits()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Visit::class, 'visitable');
}

public function visit()
{
    return $this->morphOne(Visit::class, 'visitable');
}
```

Yeah I truly don't understand what is the issue here because I can get the visitable_id and visitable_type when it is the User, but not when it is a thread. Can anyone please help me?

Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to call the relationship in the case of a thread (so $visit->visitable->channel->slug)